# IBM MQ, Send message to first queue and wait for an answer at a confirmation queue

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq, message-queue

In my setup we want to place an "Order" at order_queue and wait at the same thread until the backends sends a reply at the shipment_queue. The code is in Java.

```
private Shipment placeOrder(Order order) {

  public String sendQueue = "order_queue";
  public String replyQueue = "shipment_queue";

  final private JmsTemplate template;
  
  template.send(sendQueue, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message jmsmsg = ourConverter.toMessage(msg, session);
                jmsmsg.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                jmsmsg.setJMSExpiration(5 * Constants.MINUTE);
                jmsmsg.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                jmsmsg.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue(replyQueue));
                return jmsmsg;
            }
        });


  //AT THIS POINT I WANT TO WAIT AND GET THE MESSAGE
  New code
}
```

Currently I have another class that captures the response with a listener

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "shipment_queue")
    public void receiveOther(Message message) {
        logger.info("");
        logger.info( this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info("Received message of type: " + message.getClass().getSimpleName());
        ReplyData reply = converter.replyFromMessage(message);
        if (null != reply) {
            logger.info("Message was JSON Compliant");
            reply.logResult();
        } else {
            logger.warn("Message string was not JSON");
        }
    }
```

My goal is to have a clean function that has the responsibility to send, wait and return the result.

I would like the code to be like this:

```
private Shipment placeOrder(Order order) {
  send to first queue
  wait for the reply at the second queue
  return the reply
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like you want to have a request/response style which is total opposite of the idea of using queue. Why do you need to write your code as you described? I don't think that would be a good idea for so many reasons

Comment: this is how the customer's backend operates. This is what we have and we need to operate at the client side.

Comment: Have you looked at the [sendAndReceive](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#sendAndReceive(java.lang.String,org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator)) style of methods of the `JmsTemplate`?

Comment: @DanielSteinmann that might close to the case. But sendAndReceive sends to temporary queue? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it sends by default to a temporary queue. I assumed you are also in charge of the server code and therefore can easily use a temporary queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at pattern 107 at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Spring-JMS

> The Level 107 sample sends two message requests. For one there is an
> asynchronous listener. For the other there is a blocking synchronous
> wait.

The code you need to add to `sendSyncReply` is

```
jmsmsg.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue(replyQueue));
```

`SendMessageService107.java`

```
package com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.level107;

import com.ibm.jakarta.jms.JMSTextMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.Constants;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.data.OurData;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.data.ReplyData;
import com.ibm.mq.samples.jms.spring.globals.handlers.OurMessageConverter;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.jms.DeliveryMode;
import jakarta.jms.JMSException;
import jakarta.jms.Message;
import jakarta.jms.Session;
import java.util.UUID;


@Service
public class SendMessageService107 {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Value("${app.l107.queue.name1}")
    public String sendQueue;

    @Value("${app.l107.queue.name2}")
    public String replyQueue;

    final private JmsTemplate myNonJmsTemplate107;

    final private OurMessageConverter ourConverter = new OurMessageConverter();

    SendMessageService107(JmsTemplate myNonJmsTemplate107) {
        this.myNonJmsTemplate107 = myNonJmsTemplate107;
    }

    public void sendAsyncReply(OurData msg) {
        logger.info("Sending Message with Async Reply");
        myNonJmsTemplate107.send(sendQueue, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message jmsmsg = ourConverter.toMessage(msg, session);
                jmsmsg.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                jmsmsg.setJMSExpiration(5 * Constants.MINUTE);
                jmsmsg.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                jmsmsg.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue(replyQueue));
                return jmsmsg;
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendSyncReply(OurData msg) {
        logger.info("Sending Message with Sync Reply");
        Object reply = myNonJmsTemplate107.sendAndReceive(sendQueue, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                Message jmsmsg = ourConverter.toMessage(msg, session);
                jmsmsg.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                jmsmsg.setJMSExpiration(5 * Constants.MINUTE);
                jmsmsg.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                return jmsmsg;
            }
        });
        try {
            logger.info("Reply received");

            if (null == reply) {
                logger.info("Reply is null");
            } else if (reply instanceof JMSTextMessage) {
                logger.info("Reply is a text message, attempting to extract data");
                JMSTextMessage txtReply = (JMSTextMessage) reply;
                logger.info(txtReply.getText());
                ReplyData rr = ourConverter.replyFromMessage(txtReply);
                if (null != rr) {
                    logger.info("Have converted reply");
                    rr.logResult();
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Reply wasn't what was expected");
                }

            } else {
                logger.info("reply is not null, but of unexpected type");
                logger.info("reply is of type : " + reply.getClass());
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            logger.warn("JMSException processing reply");
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough I was looking exactly the same file, same method. However I never reach the  "logger.info("Reply received");" line. Moreover I added a comment line before the try and also the code did not reach there. Have you ever tried to execute a similar scenario?

Comment: In that case the issue will most likely be in the replier code. Check out pattern 108, which is the corresponding reply code. https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/master/Spring-JMS/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/samples/jms/spring/level108/MessageConsumer108.java

Comment: Did not completely resolved my issue, however helped to move. Thanks!